# Swift: difference between function expression and function declaration

Tags: swift, lambda, functional-programming

I would like to know the technical difference between a function expression and a function declaration in Swift, the specifics, and how it is handle by the compiler at runtime and the memory management if is possible.

```
func firstFunc(of param: [SomeType]) -> [SomeType] {
    return param.sorted(by: <)
}

let secondFunc = { (param: [SomeType]) -> [SomeType] in
    return param.sorted(by: <)
}

print(firstFunc) // (Function)
print(secondFunc) // (Function)
```

If I print any of these two functions the output is `(Function)` in both cases but I would like to know what is in the guts, and I'm not talking about the difference between a regular function/method and a closure.

Comment: I don't think there is a different other than you are storing that method in a variable. In your example here it is a constant but if you declare it as a variable you could change the method functionality over time. The first one would never change.

Comment: I understand the implications and possibilities of both approaches but I would love to know if there is any difference at a very low level, maybe performance or something like that.